# Barcode input into database fails in php

Tags: php, barcode-printing

When i scan a barcode in  "form" it automatically inserts it in database but two first digits are missing (two first zeros) . So , for example if a barcode 0020166196800002 is scanned and inserted into database only number 20166196800002 is inserted without first two digits of "00". Please, help!

Comment: Change the datatype of storing the barcode to var_char and enter it as string

Comment: its a string not an interger

Comment: i tried changing it from (int) to (varchar),(text),(string)... utf-8 encoding  and i put maxlenght ="30" in input form and still nothing..

Answer (score 2):

Databases do strip leading zeros if the column type is numeric and there is no zero padding configured.

For example, MySQL allows a column to be defined with "zerofill(x)", which results in every number being at least x digits long, and a stored zero will come up as x `0` characters instead of only one.

Comment: still nothing , i changed logic in form while checking the row in database(i cut off those two zeros while validating the form).Anyway help you very much, will be working on your solution.